# What does it mean for a shell to parse its command line and to identify the PATH?

Tags: operating-systems

After accepting the command entered by user,the shell generates a readily executable simple command line by parsing it evaluating variables(if present),performs command substitution,interprets metecharacters like * and  ?(if present) and identifies the PATH.

Can anyone explain to me in simple terms the parsing part and identifying the Path part?

*text is taken from Unix and shell programming by M.G.Venkateshurthy

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for all content originally written by others.  Copying text without credit is against our rules.  Please refer to https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing, and then [edit] your question to comply with our expectations.

Comment: This is not a grammatical sentence in English.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question about Unix and shell programming. When you run a command like `cp dir/* $destination` the shell has to do several things to simplify this command before executing it:

- Replace `dir/*` with a list of all the paths matching `dir/*` e.g. `dir/file1 dir/file2 dir/file3`
- Replace `$destination` with the value of the variable `destination` e.g. `otherdir`

There are other steps not shown here, like command substitution - for example `$(ls)` is replaced by running the command `ls` and replacing it with whatever `ls` outputs.

Finally as a last step, generally separate from the others as it does not actually edit the command, the shell has to find the actual path of the `cp` command, usually at `/bin/cp`. It does this by looking at the variable `PATH`, which holds a list of directories, then looking in each directory to find an executable called `cp`.